# Send email written in markdown using mutt

Tags: scripting, mutt

Sometimes I need to send a fragment of code on google-group inline. Text does not help here; I can type it in markdown, convert it to html (using pandoc etc.), attach to mutt as `text/html` and send it.

There is one good solution available [here](https://dgl.cx/2009/03/html-mail-with-mutt-using-markdown) but it uses external `sendmail` program to send email. I am using mutt which has capabilities to send emails <strike>over IMAP</strike> by itself.

Comment: Why not just pipe output from a command-line Markdown formatter to `sendmail`?

Comment: Hmm.. shared computer! Don't want to store password for external sendmail.

Comment: Is there any examples we can see of what your current results look like on google-groups?

Comment: Also you want to type things up in markdown, but have them rendered prior to attaching them to your emails, right?

Comment: This sounds like what you're asking for, but might need to be modified: https://dgl.cx/2009/03/html-mail-with-mutt-using-markdown. Also [markdownmail.py](https://github.com/larsks/mutt-utils/blob/master/markdownmail.py) sounded like something you could use.

Comment: @slm, Thank, I is indeed what I am using currently (I have added this link to question also) but the problem is that it uses external `sendmail` which is ok on my person computer but not on lab computer which is shared. I have tweaked it a bit but I am waiting for a better solution.

Comment: Are you sure that mutt sends emails over IMAP?

Comment: @bersch I am not sure about terminology. It uses smtp_user and smtp_password variables. I think that smtp is part of IMAP. Is it not?

Comment: @Dilawar The [Internet Message Access Protocol](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501) (IMAP) is a protocol for e-mail storage and retrieval. E-mail _transfer_ is handled by the [Simple Mail Transfer Protocol](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5321) (SMTP). They are distinct protocols.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

After you compose a message, but before sending you have lots of options available to you. Press `?` to view them.

Some that may help here:

- `F` to filter the attachment through an external processor

  - Use `pandoc -s -f markdown -t html` to convert to HTML
- `^T` to edit the attachment MIME type

  - Change from `text/plain` to `text/html`.

Now a macro that will do everything in one step. Add this to your `.muttrc`:

```
macro compose \e5 "F pandoc -s -f markdown -t html \ny^T^Utext/html; charset=utf-8\n"
set wait_key=no
```

To use this macro, after you have finished composing your message but before you send, press <kbd>Esc</kbd> then <kbd>5</kbd> to convert your markdown formatted message into HTML.

You can naturally customize this macro as you see fit. Mutt has lots of key bindings already built in, so whatever key sequence you choose to bind to, make sure it doesn't overwrite something else (or it's something you can live without).

---

The option `set wait_key=no` suppresses Mutt's `Press any key to continue...` prompt when external commands are run. If `wait_key` is `yes` (which is the default) you'll have to press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, then <kbd>5</kbd>, then any other key to continue.

Comment: This is a really elegant solution! +1

Comment: this is nice, but it's got core flaw. it eliminates the plaintext part of the email which makes it suck to read in clients like ... mutt ;)  HTML emails should have a plaintext and html component. the raw markdown should be the plaintext, the converted should be the HTML.

Comment: Agree with @masukomi, email clients in general send both html and text versions of the email. It would be nice to have a macro that adds the html version and leaves the original as text/plain.

Comment: Nevermind, it seems the issue is more complicated than expected: https://github.com/neomutt/neomutt/issues/587

Comment: In the end I've build my own setup for this http://nosubstance.me/post/mutt-secret-sauce/

Comment: @pepper_chico  I've tried running the example of MIMEmbellish linked on your page but it fails with `(23) Failed writing body`. Do you still use it?

Comment: @Rastapopoulos yes: https://github.com/oblitum/dotfiles/issues/3#issuecomment-437954693

Comment: @pepper_chico Thanks! Looks amazing! I'll try it out!

Comment: I email to work (mutt and webmail) had to change:
```charset=us-ascii```
To
```charset=utf-8```

Comment: @TonyBarganski Thanks for the tip. Since this answer is more than 6 years old, it's due for an update!

Comment: `auto_view text/html` in `.muttrc` will use w3m to render incoming html emails in plain text as formatted by the html. That's quite passable for me. There's other ways to interact, including using a browser-like experience. https://www.sendmail.org/~ca/email/mutt/manual-5.html

Answer (score 5):

You can send e-mails also as a `multipart/alternative` containing both `text/plain` and `text/html`.

Requirements: pandoc

Basically it creates from markdown message plaintext and html5. Creates attachments from those parts, marks them as inline attachments, set correct mime type and combine them into mutlipart message.

Any other attachments are supposed to be added after running this macro in compose menu. Optionally signing/encrypting message should be done as the final step

```
macro compose ,m \
"<enter-command>set pipe_decode<enter>\
<pipe-message>pandoc -f gfm -t plain -o /tmp/msg.txt<enter>\
<pipe-message>pandoc -s -f gfm -t html5 -o /tmp/msg.html<enter>\
<enter-command>unset pipe_decode<enter>a^U/tmp/msg.txt\n^Da^U/tmp/msg.html\n^D^T^Utext/html; charset=utf-8\n=DTT&d^U\n" \
"Convert markdown gfm to HTML and plain"
```

Answer (score 1):

Sendmail is often not flexible enogh for sending mails.

I use msmtp together with mutt on particular accounts for flexible SMTP.

To use it with mutt change:

```
# ~/.muttrc  
set sendmail="/usr/bin/msmtp -a default"
```

and

```
# ~/.msmtprc  
defaults
tls off
logfile ~/.msmtp.log  
account default   
host your.smtp.host  
port 25  
from your-user-name@your-host.com  
auth off  
user username  
password password
```

Answer (score 1):

I can send email in any format using `neomutt`. I just use `Emacs` (org-mode), instead of `vim`. Although, I am a `vim` user as well. But, I mostly use `Emacs` with evil-mode.

In my `.muttrc` I have set up the editor to be `emacs` instead of `vim`. When writing a new email, `neomutt` fires `emacs` up. Then I call "org-mode", write the message, and export to whatever format I want.

I can export to `PDF` format. Then I save it and attach the `PDF` file in my `/tmp`. After that I can send to whomever.

If I want the `html` format, I export that in the same way and I automatically can see the output, before sending the email.

Apart from that, there are many other export formats in org-mode. Just, choose what you want. For sending code to other people, just add the source code to whatever language you want. Everything is explained in the [org-wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/OrgMode).